# Why is *SHRRD lock HELD on a PF by job QZDASOINIT user QUSER, even after querying a new PF?

Tags: jdbc, ibm-midrange, db2-400

While querying a PF (say CUSTPF) using ACS's Run SQL Scripts, why is shared-read lock is HELD even after I've queried a new PF (say EMPPF)?

When I tried to DLCOBJ using command

```
DLCOBJ OBJ((TESTLIB/CUSTPF *FILE *SHRRD))
```

There was no change in lock state as checked using command

```
WRKOBJLCK OBJ(TESTLIB/CUSTPF) OBJTYPE(*FILE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a [pseudo closed cursor](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/pseudo-closed-cursor-faq)...

> Pseudo closed cursors are a key part of a performance optimization
> feature of IBM DB2 for i SQL. When an application closes a cursor, Db2
> for i normally closes the cursor and closes the file, deleting the ODP
> (Open Data Path). If the application runs the same statement multiple
> times, each new execution requires a full open of the target file. The
> idea behind pseudo closed cursors is to not fully close the cursor and
> file but rather to cache the cursor for potential future use. The
> cursor is left in a soft closed (or pseudo closed) state. When the
> cursor is pseudo closed, the underlying file and ODP are left open.
> All record locks are released; however, a shared lock still appears on
> the file. Db2 for i can then reuse the cursor as needed without the
> cost of a full open of the file. Db2 for i can also decide to hard
> close the pseudo closed cursor when needed.

As far as the `DLCOBJ` command not working, are you running it from another job or your ACS session?  If another job, that's not going to work.  The correct way is to actually use `ALCOBJ` from another job.
`ALCOBJ OBJ((TESTLIB/CUSTPF *FILE *EXCL)) CONFLICT(*RQSRLS)`

Note that this will of course leave your 5250 session with an exclusive lock on the file which you can than release with `DLCOBJ`.

If you were trying to `DLCOBJ` from your ACS session, that's not going to work either.  The correct way to force the close from ACS is:

- Disconnect from the database server.
- Execute the statements `DISCONNECT ALL;` `CONNECT RESET` to essentially disconnect and reconnect to the local database.